# Replicate only specific tables from Master to Slave in MySQL

Tags: mysql, master-slave

Hi Team,

```
   We have a MASTER replicating to a SLAVE. We want to create a new slave that will only replicate specific tables from the master. Please let us know how to do?
```

We added the below parameters in the slave node and tried but not working. Please let me know the steps ?
replicate-do-table=test.account_products
replicate-wild-do-table=test.account_products

Comment: which MySQL version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

On the slave side, there is an option to only apply binlog statements for certain tables. You need to add the below parameter in my.ini/my.cnf under mysqld section and also confirm with ***show slave status\G***

> replicate-do-table=databasename.tablename

Comment: I added same parameters but  it is replicating other tables also

Comment: can you share `show slave status\G` output